# Storyboard transitioning to different view controllers for different tableview cell

Tags: uitableview, storyboard, transition, segue

I have been able to find tutorials on creating the transition from one tableview to another view. The transition when you click on a cell is to the same destination view controller.  I was wondering how I could transition to different view controllers for each of the cells in the tableview.  Can I still do this with storyboard? If so, how?  If not, what alternatives can you suggest?

The storyboard has been hooked up from the tableview to a detailed view.  But this is what I would like to accomplish:

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
  if ([[segue identifier] isEqualToString:@"mytransition"]) {

    NSInteger sectionId = [[self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow] section];
    if (sectionId == 0) {
        NSLog(@"try to change the destination view controller");
        //I don't know if this is possible?!
    } else {
        NSLog(@"Proceed with the original destination view controller");
        //this is ok
    }
  }
}
```

EDIT:  I found the solution! You can view it here: http://forums.macrumors.com/showthread.php?t=1274743

In summary, the solution involved using a combination of the prepareForSegue and didSelectRowAtIndexPath for anyone who's interested.  Instead of linking each cell to another view, create another segue from the controller to each of the desired view controllers. Then check the segue identifier.

-Jen

Answer (score 3):

Jen's right.  The solution from Jen's link does work.

- Create the `segue` from the prototype cell in the table to the destination view controller.
- Set the identifier of the segue.
- Modify `didSelectRowAtIndexPath` to get the row number of the selected cell, and call `performSegueWithIdentifier` with the `segue` identifier for that cell.